# My PWA shows up in the share tray of my Android device, but when sharing to it the text doesn't show in the query params. How can I find out why?

Tags: web, progressive-web-apps, web-share-target

I have the following snippet on my web manifest `manifest.webmanifest`:

```json
  "share_target": {
    "action": "/",
    "method": "GET",
    "params": {
      "url": "dirtyurl",
      "title": "title",
      "text": "bodyText"
    }
  }
```

So I'd expect that when a user selects the app in the share tray I'd get something like `https://mywebsite.com/?dirtyurl=someurl&title=titleofarticle&bodyText=textofsomething`, right? But when I display `window.location.href` on the website I get just `https://mywebsite.com/`.

Since this is an PWA installed on Android, I can't really see the dev tools to see if any error was posted. And for some reason the app doesn't show on the Windows 11 share tray at all so I cannot check on my computer's debug tools.

So, why is the Web Share Target API property not working as intended? I have been trying to follow the MDN guide here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/share_target but I can't find any reason why the URL isnt being populated as it should.

Thank you!